# JBox2D becomes very slow on mobile phones after 80-90 dynamic and static bodies

Tags: box2d

I have a simple game with 20-30 physics bodies (static, and dynamic)

If I add some additional Dynamic bodies and joints (over 80-90 item), then JBox2D will become very laggy, and a little slow.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the limit of JBox2D? If I change to Box2D JNI via java native calls, will it be faster?

Comment: I have no idea what hardware you are running on, but I think for a mobile game, that might be too much for most phones to handle.

Comment: Joints are generally quite expensive to use too I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response for Android devices. Jbox2D is so bad... Since NDK is available, i use it with native Box2D. January 2010, there was a 3X factor without garbage collector lags. There is many NDK ports as in [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

note: With 2.3 devices, the new GC fixes lags...